# Omit space between selected variables

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I have one data sets with name DATA_TEST.This data frame contain 7-observations in character format.You can see table below.

```
#DATA SET
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(
  Ten_digits=c("NA","207","0101","0208 90","0206 90 99 00","103","9706 00 00 00"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
View(DATA_TEST)
```

[image]

So my intention is to convert this data frame with a stringr or other package like picture below. Actually the code needs to do one thing or more precisely first must found only variables with 10 digits like "0206 90 99 00" or "9706 00 00 00" and convert this variables into variables without space "0206909900" and "9706000000". In the table below you can see finally what the table should look like.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far using `stringr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `stringr` and `dplyr`:

```
DATA_TEST %>%
 mutate(Ten_digits = if_else(str_count(Ten_digits, "[0-9]") == 10,
                            str_replace_all(Ten_digits, fixed(" "), ""),
                            Ten_digits))

  Ten_digits
1         NA
2        207
3       0101
4    0208 90
5 0206909900
6        103
7 9706000000
```

Or with `stringr` and `base R`:

```
with(DATA_TEST, ifelse(str_count(Ten_digits, "[0-9]") == 10,
                        str_replace_all(Ten_digits, fixed(" "), ""),
                        Ten_digits))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to calculate number of characters after removing whitespaces and replace only the value where number of characters are 10.

```
temp <- gsub("\\s", "", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits)
DATA_TEST$Ten_digits[nchar(temp) == 10] <- temp[nchar(temp) == 10]

DATA_TEST
#  Ten_digits
#1         NA
#2        207
#3       0101
#4    0208 90
#5 0206909900
#6        103
#7 9706000000
```